# How to uninstall a running app through code?

Tags: android, uninstallation

I have a requirement in my app that after a specified number of unsuccessful login attempts:

1. A folder on the sdcard essential for the app be deleted and
2. The app be uninstalled from the device.

This is basically a self destruct sort of action.

Can you provide inputs on whether the aspect of uninstalling the app, while the app is running is feasible? I assume deletion of the folder must be easy. Do you foresee any issues with doing that too.

Thanks
A

Comment: Imagine some other app is using that folder? What do you think will happen? Or the user has made that folder read-only (no modify or write permissions)?

Comment: For this scenario, we can safely assume the situation where this app is the only app on the device . For the other scenario, can there be a way to stop from making that particular folder read only?

Answer (score 1):

There's no public API to allow you to seamlessly remove a package (including your own.)  You can request a package be removed by firing an `Intent` with the action set to `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE`, but the user will be notified of the action as it will take them to the default installer (ie Google Play Store) to perform the action.

Answer (score 0):

Larry Schiefer is right, there is (fortunately) no public API to do this without user interaction. But if you have extended rights, for example if the device is rooted and your app has root access, you could use the command line:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "pm uninstall com.example.yourapplication"})
```

In the case you have special privileges because you are a system app, you can use hidden API's, which are very dangerous because they are undocumented and can change from one Android update to the next. However, if you are in control which version of the OS installed, you might get away with it.

In this case, you could call [`PackageManager.deletePackage`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#1777) through reflection.

```
pm = context.getPackageManager();
Class<?>[] types = new Class[] {String.class, IPackageDeleteObserver.class, int.class};
method = pm.getClass().getMethod("deletePackage", types);
method.invoke(pm, new Object[] {"com.example.com", null, 0})
```

This function *should* also delete all your package data, so it's a complete wipe. You need to ask for the DELETE_PACKAGES permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` (which is only granted if you are a system app/system user):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
```

Comment: Of course, you can always try to use reflection or leverage a rooted device.  But, that's not very portable at all and definitely not forward compatible.  Hidden APIs are not guaranteed to be untouched in future versions of Android.  My assumption is that the poster is targeting commercially released devices and using only public SDK exposed APIs.

Comment: I know, your answer is the correct answer for commercially released devices. I just took the inverse assumption: the device is under total control of @angela-sim. This seems to be what she's applying in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016313/how-to-uninstall-a-running-app-through-code/22017096?noredirect=1#comment33373342_22016313): "*For this scenario, we can safely assume the situation where this app is the only app on the device*".

Comment: Hi Larry and Menno, thanks for your insights, and yes you have quoted me in an accurate context, this is not a typical commercial app and definitely wont be published commercially. Implementing the self destruct is of utmost importance most preferably without any user interaction.

Comment: @AngelaSim I edited my response with a method to do this as a system app. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Menno Thank you so much for this hint. I will surely keep you posted on my progress.